# Multiple subscribe to one Rx.Subject

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I try to create an observable with Rx.Subject that will be subscribe by multiple components.

I have my WebsocketService :

```
export class WebsocketService {
private ws = null;
private subject: Rx.Subject<{}>;

constructor() {
}

public connect(url): Rx.Subject<{}> {
    if (!this.subject) {
        this.subject = this.create(url);
        console.log('Successfully connected: ' + url);
    } else {
        console.log('Already connected: ' + url);
    }
    return this.subject;
}

private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (this.ws === null) {
        console.log('Connected to WS');
        this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    } else {
        console.log('Already connected to WS');
    }

    const observable = Rx.Observable.create(
        (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
            this.ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
            this.ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
            this.ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
            return this.ws.close.bind(this.ws);
        });

    return Rx.Subject.create({}, observable);
}
}
```

And two components that subscribe int the same way :

```
// ...
constructor(private stationService: StationService, private websocketService: WebsocketService) {

    websocketService.connect('ws://localhost:8080/ws')
        .subscribe(msg => {
            console.log(msg);
            console.log('[Dashboard] Response from websocket: ' + msg.data);
        });
}
// ...
```

And the second :

```
// ...
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private websocketService: WebsocketService) {

    websocketService.connect('ws://localhost:8080/ws')
        .subscribe(msg => {
            console.log(msg);
            console.log('[Station] Response from websocket: ' + msg.data);

        });
}
// ...
```

We i refresh, the two components call my service :

Connected to WS websocket.service.ts:26:12
   Successfully connected: ws://localhost:8080/ws websocket.service.ts:17:12
   Already connected: ws://localhost:8080/ws

But when i send something one the socket i have only one subscriber that responde :

[Dashboard] Response from websocket: qwerty

Someone call help me to find my mistake ?

Thanks,

Comment: are both of your components initialized properly after serving your app, so that these subscriptions are registered? Or is it just that you are on your dashboard page and hence only Dashboard component is initialized when you checked your console?

Comment: Yes both are initialized, in my console i see "Successfully connected" and "Already connected" that means that WebsocketService.connetc is call 2 times.
And if i comment th first subscribe, the second works. It's strange

Comment: It looks good and as it is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-omdef8 it should be working. 

What you could try is to get rid of your custom observable like this

const observable = new Subject<any>(); 
            this.ws.onmessage = (msg) => observable.next(msg);
            this.ws.onerror = (err) => observable.error(err);
            this.ws.onclose = () => observable.complete();
        });
return observable

Answer (score 0):

Thank's you Bene.

I just change :

```
    const observable = Rx.Observable.create(
         (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
             this.ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
             this.ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
             this.ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
             return this.ws.close.bind(this.ws);
    });

    return Rx.Subject.create({}, observable);
```

To :

```
    const observable = new Subject<MessageEvent>();

    this.ws.onmessage = (msg) => observable.next(msg);
    this.ws.onerror = (err) => observable.error(err);
    this.ws.onclose = () => observable.complete();

    return observable;
```

And it work's !

If someone have more detail of why the first solution didn't works, let me know.